# Pygame doesn't play audio

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pygame

def speak(audioString):
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('audio.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

speak('hello')
```

It creates the 'audio.mp3' file, but I can't hear anything. Any conjectures?
Maybe I should use something else?

Comment: Are you able to play this audio file using conventional audio players?

Answer (score 2):

play function is async and returns immediately, so you should add something to stall and wait before exiting.

And to be sure that you are not waiting so long, you can use this snippet:

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Edit: there is even a better way to do this, use `pygame.event.wait()`, which will wait for all the async tasks to end.

Comment: In my one experience with Pygame, I used `play()` in a similar manner as OP, without any wait after calling it, and audio played as expected. I suspect something else is the problem here though I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the .mp3 file into .ogg - the latter extension is officially supported in the pygame library documents. The conversion solved *one* of the issues I had experienced.